# Oracle 11g Express Edition: /etc/init.d/functions:No such file or function

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, oracle11gr2

I am trying to install Oracle 11g following this link on Ubuntu 14.04:[Link to install the Oracle 11g Express Edition](http://sysadminnotebook.blogspot.in/2012/10/installing-oracle-11g-r2-express.html).The problem arises right after i start configuring and right after the configuration is over.It shows "Successful installation" but then displays an error.

```
sourajyoti@:Disk1$ sudo /etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe: line 69: /etc/init.d/functions: No such file or directory

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration
------------------------------------------------- 
This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 11g Express 
Edition.The following questions will determine whether the database should be starting 
upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that will be used for database accounts.  
Press <Enter> to accept the defaults.Ctrl-C will abort.
Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express[8080]:
Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:   
Port 1521 appears to be in use by another application. Specify a different port.
Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:1522
Specify a password to be used for database accounts.Note that the same password will 
be used for SYS and SYSTEM.Oracle recommends the use of different passwords 
for each database account.This can be done after initial configuration:
Confirm the password:

Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...Done
Starting Oracle Database 11g Express Edition instance...Done
Installation completed successfully.
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe: line 177: /etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe: No such file or directory
sourajyoti@:Disk1$ sudo service oracle-xe start
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe: line 69: /etc/init.d/functions: No such file or directory
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition is not configured.You must run '/etc/init.d/
oracle-xe configure' as the root user to configure the database.
```

Is there any way to overcome this problem?

Comment: Do you have /etc/init.d/functions?

Comment: No it is accessed if the distribution is a red-hat release.It should not even satisfy the if condition for whether it is a redhat release.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this

**/etc/init.d/oracle-xe: line 177: /etc/sysconfig/oracle-xe: No such file or directory**

in ubuntu, go to the file  **/etc/init.d/oracle-xe** and search for the line: **CONFIGURATION="/etc/sysconfig/$CONFIG_NAME"** change this to: 
**CONFIGURATION="/etc/default/$CONFIG_NAME"**